# Full with background with fixed with content

Tags: html, css, layout, grid, css-position

I've got the following two containers that should be 1400px width in total. The problem in my code is that the background isn't 100% width when I want the two containers to be 1400px.

How can I achieve this the best way? I hope you guys get my problem.

I am using the following code:

```css
.wrapper {
  max-width: 1400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 50px;
}

#left-container {
  width: 50%;
  background: blue;
  float: left;
}

#right-container {
  width: 50%;
  background: green;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <div id="left-container">

    <h2>Left container</h2>

  </div>

  <div id="right-container">

    <h2>Right container</h2>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: On the containers? Could you specify this, please?

Comment: it is not full width because you set "padding: 0 50px;" that mean padding from right and left 50px.

Comment: Let me get this straight: You want to have the background spread the full width of the page(even if the page is more than 1400px), while having the containers at 700px?

Comment: @Iulius yeah, the only important thing is that the two containers are 1400px in total so that it matches the rest of the layout

Answer (score 0):

You can use pseudo element in addition to background for the coloration and you can have some overflow:

```css
.wrapper {
  max-width: 1400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding:0 50px;
}

#left-container {
  width: 50%;
  background: blue;
  float: left;
  position:relative;
}
#left-container:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  left:-100vw;
  right:100%;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  background:inherit;
}

#right-container {
  width: 50%;
  background: green;
  float: left;
  position:relative;
}
#right-container:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  right:-100vw;
  left:100%;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  background:inherit;
}
body {
 overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <div id="left-container">

    <h2>Left container</h2>

  </div>

  <div id="right-container">

    <h2>Right container</h2>

  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in many ways. The most simple solution I can think of now is to add a container and use a linear gradient:

```css
body {margin:0; padding:0;}
.container {
  background: linear-gradient(to left, blue 50%, green 50%);
}
.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid white;
  max-width: 1400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: auto;
}

#left-container,
#right-container{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  padding-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div id="left-container">
      <h2>Left container</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="right-container">
      <h2>Right container</h2>
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```