# Sidebar background color beyond the sidebar CSS

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Weird title, but can't describe it better in one sentence. The problem is I have centered Bootstrap container with 3 col sidebar and 9 col content area.

I need to set background color to color everything from the sidebar all the way to the left (to the left browser window edge). Now, let's check the picture to better understand what I mean:

[image]
[image]

I tried simple hack:

```
background: linear-gradient(
    to right, 
    #666 0%, 
    #666 25%, 
    #fff 25%, 
    #fff 100%
);
```

but this approach is not responsive - so it breaks on small devices and really wide displays too.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">...</div>
        <div class="col-sm-9">...</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you share your html

Comment: @DanOswalt Pretty basic Bootstrap markup... added

Comment: possible duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52505735/full-with-background-with-fixed-with-content/52505826#52505826

Comment: also related : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50257456/stretch-left-side-of-image-outside-container-to-edge-of-the-page/50257633#50257633

Comment: change col-sm-9 to col-9 and col-sm-3 to col-3. this should work

Comment: @DeepakVerma the issue is elsewhere - has nothing to do with the Bootstrap itself. The question is - how to colour background from the sidebar right border all the way to the left browser window (which is beyond the sidebar column). It definitely requires hack of some sort, but the one I tried isn't responsive.